# How can I get a collection from FireStore?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve the whole collection from Firestore and following instructions step by step but all the time there are some errors either map() or, Observable or then() doesn't exist or work.

That's how I've been trying to get it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './employee';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  FormData: Employee;

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  getEmployees(){
    this.firestore.collection('employees').get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

That's what I get for now:

ERROR in src/app/employees/shared/employee.service.ts(16,50): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead using `valueChanges()`. `valueChanges()` returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects.

```
getEmployees(){
  this.firestore.collection('employees')
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(docs => {
      // loop through each item in the array and log value
      docs.forEach(doc => console.log(doc));
    });
}
```

This comes from the documentation for [valueChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#streaming-collection-data). In case you need to doc id, you can instead use [snapshotChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges) in combination with RxJS pipeable operators such as `map()` (to create an array of objects with both the id and data):

```
getEmployees(){
  this.firestore.collection('employees')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
       map(actions => actions.map(a => {
         const data = a.payload.doc.data();
         const id = a.payload.doc.id;
         return { id, ...data };
       });
    )
    .subscribe(docs => {
      // loop through each item in the array and log value
      docs.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.id));
    });
}
```

Ideally you should create a `class` or `interface` to represent the data structure of each "employee" and use that to strongly type the response:

Service:

```
interface Employee {
  someProperty: number;
  anotherProperty: string;
  yetAnotherProperty: boolean;
}

// ...

// perhaps return the observable so a component using this service can consume the data (can't return from inside subscribe())
getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
  return this.firestore.collection<Employee>('employees').valueChanges();

  /* or instead snapshotChanges() with map()
    return this.firestore.collection<Employee>('employees')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
       });
    )
  */
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({ /* ... */})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(employees => console.log(employees));
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Will I be able to catch doc’s id this way? Because I read that using valueChanges() you can retrieve the json file but without their ids. Is that true?

Comment: `valueChanges()`, will not return the id, but the documentation indicates `snapshotChanges()` will. Did you get a chance to read any documentation about @angular/fire? I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve skimmed over it. Just getting into the way of things with Firebase. I cannot get why I get those errors if it works for others 

Comment: The documentation provides good example of usage. Unlike standard Firestore JS, @angular/fire instead heavily utilizes RxJS observables so often trying to do something `then()` will cause errors.

Comment: Your solution works well for me  thanks for help! Now I’ll try to find out how to do that same with with snapshot

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! I updated the answer to show how to use snapshotChanges().

Comment: Anyway I had to erase Observable <Employee> so that it works for me 